# Xcode WebApp - Not Centered when launched on iPhone/Safari

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm doing my first Xcode WebApp - below is the View Controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  iOS8SwiftWebViewTutorial
//
//  Created by Administrator on 26/09/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Administrator. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let url = "https://japanese.dating"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

}
```

It launches on the Simulator and my physical iphone.

The only issue is what ever site I put into the code - even sites like www.google.com I find its not centered.

[image]

Thanks-you :)

Comment: Do you position your view using Autolayout? I wondering if it's the position of the WebView or the content which is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the webView should fill the screen then you can use:

```
webView.frame = self.view.frame
```

place that in your viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using StoryBoard check your constraints.

You can center it using **center horizontally in container** constraint and use equal width.

You can also change constraint like this or other

[image: center]

if you don't know how to set constraint you can refer to this tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Or you can do it programmatically set web view frame to your container view.

```
yourWebView.frame = self.view.frame
```